# Jhipster with jdk-11

Tags: jhipster

I created a project with JHipster 6.0.0-beta.0 and java version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15 LTS

I get the following error.

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project mx: Fatal error compiling: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException -> [Help 1]

Any suggestions how to solve it?

Comment: You should add it as a solution rather than a comment.

Answer (score 2):

```
The solution is:

Add the following under <!-- For JPA static metamodel generation -->

<path>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>${jaxb-runtime.version}</version>
</path>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your pom.xml what is the value of balise Java. Version